# VNC Viewer account disabled

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I recently tried to log in to one of my remote raspberry Pi boxes running Raspberian using RealVNC but when I tried to log in I noticed "The account is disabled" message.

[image: VNC Viewer Client error (account info removed)]

Googling only pointed me to RealVNC's website that says this was done due to EU data handling laws and I just needed to log in and check a box that I am 16 or older to restore my account.

Clicking the "Manage Account Online" link from within (RealVNC) VNC viewer brings one to a page that uses the same box and button for signup & login.
However, upon submitting my previously working email address (as stored within VNC Viewer), I not only am prompted to check boxes to assert I am over 16 and agree to the TOS, but am also prompted to set a new password. While it seemed like my account may not have been found, I nevertheless checked the 'I am over 16' box and generated a new password as this appeared to be my only option. They sent me a confirmation email for the account, but I am still unable to login to my remote box.

- What happened? Is there another reason Real VNC has disabled my account?
- Is there any way to log in to this box without physical access (it's more than 5 hrs away from me)?

Comment: RealVNC support should be able to help you sort this out.

Comment: The other questions about VNC viewer are technical ones; analogously, technical questions about software tools and licensing systems are okay on S.O., but [questions about using software licenses are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing).  The other side of this is I think you are wasting your time asking here; you would be much better off asking on the Pi Foundation's official forum or contacting Real VNC directly.  However, I was not aware of the license arrangement in Raspbian so I've reopened this, all apologies.

Comment: (Note though that if anyone here was having the same problem, I'm sure they would have left a comment, closed or not.  You also might want to clarify the thing about the Raspbian licensing since I suspect that's why you are collecting downvotes -- none of them are from me.)

Comment: did you use the same password as before? ... the RPi has to be able to log into your account before it can establish a connection.

Comment: @jsotola I believe so.

Comment: @goldilocks I suspect the down votes were because I originally didn't catch the fact that the end-to-end system was actually RealVNC and VNC Viewer is just the front end to connect from the client.  If I get I solution from RealVNC / The Pi Foundation I'll post it here.

Comment: this only goes to show that a remote device requires to have a watchdog program that can reset the device in case of failure such as this. .... you could also have an automatic power cycle at a specified time every day so that the RPi can re-establish baseline programs every day..

Comment: @jsotola the device is behind a firewall and has a dynamic IP, resetting the device wouldn't help when my VNC vendor deleted my account.  A dynamic IP service might of been a good backup plan.

Comment: @virtualxtc, it would have re-established the connection once your account was renewed .... you could also have it go to an external web page to get its configuration (with some type of encryption) ..... maybe a shared google drive page

Comment: Hmmm, is this the same problem? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/83904/5538

Comment: @goldilocks It's unclear as the other user doesn't seem to be noticing the account error.  I added a pic of mine to help the other user determine if they are having the same issue.

Comment: RealVNC sent me a message back saying it was due to the European Law change and that I just need to reset my password...   I think this may have just been coupled with making their password requirements more strickt.