# VNC viewer and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vnc

After I login to Raspberry Pi 3 using VNC viewer from my laptop I get this and I can't go back into desktop (original one when the pi boots up). If any one knows what is happening, then please help.

I have a Windows laptop where RealVNC viewer is installed. I have Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian where RealVNC server is enabled. Pi was connected through ethernet cable with the laptop with shared network connection. So, with the help of VNC viewer I was able to use GUI of Raspberry Pi. It **WAS** working properly. I can use the Pi console through PuTTY using SSH, but I can't get the GUI that I used to get when the Raspberry Pi booted for the first time (the normal one).

I have tried everything to go back to desktop, but failed.
[image]

Comment: If this suddenly started happening (i.e., it was working before), have a look at this question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/83792/5538 There's no solution there, but it would corroborate the assertion that something is wrong with the license included with Raspbian.

Comment: The question is unclear, and fundamentally unanswerable - What OS? What vncserver? What vncviewer?

Comment: i have windows laptop where realvnc viewer is installed. i have raspberry pi 3 with raspbian where realvnc server is enabled. pi was connected through ethernet cable with the laptop with shared network connection.so , with the help of vnc viewer i was able to use GUI of raspberrypi .it WAS working properly . i can use the pi console through PUTTY using ssh but i can't get the GUI that  i used to get when the raspberry pi booted for the first time(the normal one).@Milliways

Comment: yes, it suddenly started happening.i don't know what should i do . i had just compiled and installed opencv. @goldilocks

Comment: When you're connected you can find out what the screen resolution is, to do this open the Session information dialog from the realvnc viewer's toolbar. There should be a line that says "Size", tell us the value printed next to it.

Comment: it's 1024*768 @srk

Comment: i disabled vnc server of rasbperrypi through PUTTY (ssh ) using "raspi-config " command line and disabling from "interfacing options". after that,  rebooting raspberry pi leads  to a black background with "wastebasket" icon only when seen in monitor using hdmi.